# Dynamic 2D soft shadows with concave polygons?

Tags: 2d, lighting, shadows

I've implemented dynamic 2D soft shadows from [this article](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/graphics-programming-and-theory/dynamic-2d-soft-shadows-r2032) on gamedev.net.  It uses an image for the penubmra and is fast, physically accurate and looks good in most situations, so I really like the technique.

The problem is that it doesn't work properly for concave polygons, two polygons being close together, or a polygon being small compared to the light source.  The polygons in my app are going to be user generated, so I can't easily avoid these scenarios.

Is there a technique that still looks good an accurate in the situations that I listed?

Comment: Detect concave polygons and convert them to convex when the user finishes submiting it, its the approach for other lighting systems and even physics.